# Accessing private members of surrounding class

Tags: c++, class, declaration, inner-classes, access-control

I have two classes like this:

```c
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        class B {
            public:
                void    printX(void) const { std::cout << A::x << std::endl; }
        };
    private:
        int x;
};
```

Obviously this piece of code doesn't work because `B` can't access `x`, but is there a way to make it work?

I've tried using `friend class` keyword in both classes like this:

```c
class A {
    public:
        class B {
            public:
            friend class A;
                void    printX(void) const { std::cout << A::x << std::endl; }
        };
        friend class B;
    private:
        int x;
};
```

But it didn't work either, and I can't figure out if it's even possible.

Comment: `A` and `B` will have unrelated instances, no matter what.

Comment: In class B there is no `A` object to access. You are trying to access `x` in the same way you would if it was a static member of `A`

Comment: Are you by any chance coming from Java? Because while this code makes no sense in C++, a very similar syntax declares a capturing class instance in Java.

Comment: class B is a separate class. It does not know, the x of which A instance you want to print. What do you actually want to achieve? You could make x static, provide an A as parameter to printX, let B inherit from A, store a pointer or reference to an A inside B. All those solutions are totally different from each other. As it stands the simplest solution is to move printX into A.

Comment: Once you use any of the solutions provided by @Sebastian you will find that B can indeed access the private x member of A.

Comment: This is for a c++ school project, I have to implement an iterator over a red-black tree, the problem is that the root of the tree can change and I want to keep track of the root inside of the iterator

Comment: Then give the iterator a reference to the root, so it knows which tree it is operating on.

Comment: Put a reference member variable pointing to the tree into the iterator

Comment: @RaymondChen yes but if I use a reference, then I can't have a default constructor for my iterator, and I also tried using a pointer pointing to the root but for some reason the root doesnt change when I swap the root with another tree for example

Comment: Could you clarify both points, please? Why do you need a default constructor for the iterator? What do you specifically swap and which result do you expect?

Comment: @Fayeure What would a default iterator mean? It can't iterate any tree.

Comment: If you want to keep track of the root of the tree, and the tree's root can change, you need to keep track of the tree. But it's very unclear what good keeping track of it could do.

Comment: You would point to the tree and access the root from there. But if the tree changes, probably your iterator should get invalid? [BTW about your first idea: friend only helps with private / public, it does not provide a pointer to an object. If you used public everywhere, it would not add anything to it.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (14.7 Nested classes)

> 1 **A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as
> any other member.** The members of an enclosing class have no special
> access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause
> 14) shall be obeyed.

The problem with the provided code is that `x` is not a static data member of the class `A`. You need to provide an object of the class `A` the data member `x` of which will be accessed within an object of the nested class.

For example

```
    class A {
    public:
        class B {
        public:
            void    printX( const A &a ) const { std::cout << a.x << std::endl; }
        };
    private:
        int x;
    };

    A::B().printX( A() );
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message should tell you, `A::x` isn’t a static member so you need an *object instance* to access it. If you add a reference to instance of `A` to `B::A`, you can use that to access `A::x`.

For example, the following works:

```
class A {
    public:
        class B {
            public:
                B(A const& a) : a(a) {}
                void printX(void) const { std::cout << a.x << std::endl; }

            private:
                A const& a;
        };
    private:
        int x;
};
```

Note that using a reference member has several implications. Notably, you can now no longer reassign instances of type `A::B`, nor are its instances movable. As a consequence, it’s often convenient to hold a *pointer* rather than a reference to `A` inside `A::B`. Either way, you’ll need to ensure that instances of `A::B` do not outlive the `A` instance they refer to, otherwise you end up with a dangling reference.